# OpenOffice XML: how are fixed rows stored?

Tags: xml, mapping, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice, I can freeze a row at the top so that is fixed while scrolling. I'd like to access this information in the XML extracted from the .ods file.

My first assumption was that, along the lines of the format specification, `table:table-header-rows` would be the element for the fixed row(s). However, this is not the case.

Studying the specification on the OO web page and the ECMA specification, I couldn't find any information where this fact might be stored by OO. Does anybody here have an idea that might help me?

---

edit1: I wanted to do a diff of the content.xml before and after freezing a row. Interestingly, if the only thing I do is freezing the row, I cannot save – it seems, freezing is not considered a store-worthy change or a change at all. If I just press `Del` on an empty cell, I can save; comparing these files shows no difference.

---

(As a side note: I wanted to have a look at OO's xml-dev mailing list but sadly the links on the OO webpage are outdated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in settings.xml from the ODS file.  The relevant config item names seem to be `VerticalSplitMode`, `VerticalSplitPosition`, and `PositionBottom`.  They are listed at https://wiki.oasis-open.org/office/Spreadsheet_View_Data.

The following values freeze the first row.

```
<config:config-item config:name="VerticalSplitMode" config:type="short">2</config:config-item>
<config:config-item config:name="VerticalSplitPosition" config:type="int">1</config:config-item>
<config:config-item config:name="PositionBottom" config:type="int">1</config:config-item>
```

Related code is from Example.java at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jopendocument/YjySTc9zcCQ.  However it does not seem to work correctly, presumably because of changes in recent versions of OpenOffice.

```java
final Element splitMode = (Element) spread.getXPath("./config:config-item[@config:name='VerticalSplitMode']").selectSingleNode(sheetSettings);
// 0 to disable
splitMode.setText("1");
final Element splitPos = (Element) spread.getXPath("./config:config-item[@config:name='VerticalSplitPosition']").selectSingleNode(sheetSettings);
// height in pixels
splitPos.setText("64");
```